# Big quotes drawn with TiKz does not compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, punctuation

### My problem

Sorry to give such a long code but my problem appears in it.

I don't see why the first long code given below does not work : more precisely, the problem comes from the big quotes drawn using TiKz. I've just adapted the secund code by changing some names. Any clue to fix my long code ?

### The bugging code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\newcommand\bracket[1]{(#1)}

\newcommand\latex{\verb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Latex}{Verbatim}{numbers=left,numbersep=2mm}

% == PACKAGES USED == %

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\usepackage[x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

% == DEF : quote == %

\makeatletter
% Inline mode
    \renewcommand\quote{%
        \@ifstar{\@quoteStar}{\@quoteNoStar}%
    }
    \newcommand\@quoteStar[2][]{%
        \textquote*[#1]{\textit{#2}}
    }
    \newcommand\@quoteNoStar[2][]{%
        \textquote[#1]{\textit{#2}}
    }

% Default settings for quoting blocks
    \definecolor{bigQuoteColorNormal}{named}{black}
    \definecolor{bigQuoteColorBack}{named}{LightBlue1}

    \newlength{\bigQuoteBorderWidth}
    \setlength{\bigQuoteBorderWidth}{0pt}
    \newlength{\bigQuoteInnerMargin}
    \setlength{\bigQuoteInnerMargin}{2pt}
    \newlength{\bigQuoteOuterMarginHorizontal}
    \setlength{\bigQuoteOuterMarginHorizontal}{15pt}

% Frame for quoting blocks
    \mdfdefinestyle{quoteFrameStyle}{
        fontcolor         = bigQuoteColorNormal,%
        backgroundcolor   = bigQuoteColorBack,%
        linewidth         = \bigQuoteBorderWidth,%
        leftmargin        = \bigQuoteOuterMarginHorizontal,%
        rightmargin       = \bigQuoteOuterMarginHorizontal,%
        innerleftmargin   = \bigQuoteInnerMargin,%
        innerrightmargin  = \bigQuoteInnerMargin,%
        innertopmargin    = \bigQuoteInnerMargin,%
        innerbottommargin = \bigQuoteInnerMargin,%
    }

% The big quotes
    \newcommand*\bigQuotefont{\fontfamily{fxl}} % selects Libertine for quote font

    \newcommand*{\bigQuoteOpening}{%
        \tikz[%
            remember picture,%
            overlay,%
            xshift=-15pt,%
            yshift=-10pt%
        ]
        \node (OQ) {\bigQuotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont``};
        \kern0pt
    }
    \newcommand*{\bigQuoteClosing}{%
        \tikz[
            remember picture,
            overlay,
            xshift=15pt,
            yshift=-10pt
        ]
        \node (CQ) {\bigQuotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont''};
    }

% Block mode
    \pgfkeys{
        /quote/.is family,
        /quote,
            author/.initial = {},
            title/.initial  = {},
            editor/.initial = {}
    }
    \newenvironment{Quote}[1][]{%
% Management of the keys.
        \pgfkeys{/quote, #1}
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/quote/author}{\@author}
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/quote/title}{\@title}
        \pgfkeysgetvalue{/quote/editor}{\@editor}
% Let's go !
        \medskip
        \begin{mdframed}[style=quoteFrameStyle]
        \quoteRefFormatBefore{\@author}%
                             {\@title}%
                             {\@editor}%
    }{%
        \quoteRefFormatAfter{\@author}%
                            {\@title}%
                            {\@editor}%
        \end{mdframed}
        \medskip
    }
% 1  -->  Author
% 2  -->  Title
% 3  -->  Editor
    \newcommand\quoteRefFormatBefore[3]{%
        \bigQuoteOpening % Problem !!!
    }
% 1  -->  Author
% 2  -->  Title
% 3  -->  Editor
    \newcommand\quoteRefFormatAfter[3]{{
        \footnotesize
        \par\smallskip
        \hfill #1
        \par
        \hfill \quote*{#2}
        \par
        \hfill {\scriptsize#3} \bigQuoteClosing % Problem !!!
    }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\bigQuoteOpening

\end{document}
```

### Working code for big quotes

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%   \usepackage{libertine} % or any other font package (or none)
    \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}

% Make commands for the quotes
    \newcommand*\quotefont{\fontfamily{fxl}} % selects Libertine for quote font

    \newcommand*{\openquote}{%
        \tikz[
            remember picture,
            overlay,
            xshift=-15pt,
            yshift=-10pt
        ]
        \node (OQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont``};
        \kern0pt
    }
    \newcommand*{\closequote}{%
        \tikz[
            remember picture,
            overlay,
            xshift=15pt,
            yshift=-10pt
        ]
        \node (CQ) {\quotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont''};
    }

% wrap everything in its own environment
    \newenvironment{shadequote}{%
        \begin{quote}\openquote %
    }{%
        \hfill\closequote\end{quote} %
    }

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \newcommand*\bigQuotefont{\fontfamily{fxl}} % selects Libertine for quote font

    \newcommand*{\bigQuoteClosing}{%
        \tikz[
            remember picture,
            overlay,
            xshift=15pt,
            yshift=-10pt
        ]
        \node (CQ) {\bigQuotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont''};
    }
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{shadequote}
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams}
\end{shadequote}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I know it is same work, but you could have really tried to generate a [*minimal* working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), i.e. removed all extra things. Actually in a good amount of cases people find the cause of the trouble while doing that.

Comment: `pgfkeys` is loaded by TikZ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seem to be `[french]{babel}` related. After I remove the package it starts working. However it isn't a issue with the quotes (which `babel` makes active for some languages) because the issue stays when I remove them.

Instead if you write `\tikz[<options>]`**`{`**`\node (<name>) { .. };`**`}`** instead of
`\tikz[<options>] \node (<name>) { .. };` then it works as well with `babel`.

---

The reason why this is happening it that `babel` makes the `;` an active character (like e.g. `~`) and the `\tikz` macro looks for it as an end-marker. TikZ is smart enough programmed to recognize the situation when `;` is active and adapts. The issue here is that the `;` is changed by `babel` *at the begin of the document* (`\begin{document}`). In the preamble it is still normal! Because you store it there in an environment these `;`s are not active (catcodes are fixes as soon the character are read the first time), and `\tikz` fails to find them. If you use `\tikz { \node {..}; }` it works because `\tikz` doesn't need to look for a `;`. The inner rules to handle `;` are different (I think TikZ checks always for an normal or active `;`), so the inner `\node {..};` works fine.

Comment: @projetmbc: I tracked the issue further down and updated my answer.

Comment: No problem with pgf 2.1 CVS but you need to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`in the two cases !

Comment: Everything is clearier now.

Answer (score 3):

With pgf 2.1 CVS, the  first code works fine for me with

```
 \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
```

but with

```
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

And the second code doesn't work if you remove

```
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The main code but I removed some parts ...

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}   
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[x11names,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mdframed}       
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}   
\usepackage{csquotes} 

....

% The big quotes
    \newcommand*\bigQuotefont{\fontfamily{fxl}} % selects Libertine for quote font

    \newcommand*{\bigQuoteOpening}{%
        \tikz[%
            remember picture,%
            overlay,%
            xshift=-15pt,%
            yshift=-10pt%
        ]
        \node (OQ) {\bigQuotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont``}; 
        \kern0pt 
    }
    \newcommand*{\bigQuoteClosing}{%
       \tikz[
            remember picture,
            overlay,
            xshift=15pt,
            yshift=-10pt
        ]
        \node (CQ) {\bigQuotefont\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont''}; 
    }

 ...


\begin{document}

\bigQuoteOpening 
A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely
foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools.\par\emph{Douglas Adams} 
\bigQuoteClosing

\end{document}
```

[image]